# OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener implemented between apps with sharedUserID?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-sharedpreferences

I have App A and App B under sharedUserId. In App B, I would like to get the sharedPreferences of A, when they change. Right now I can get app A's sharedPreferences, but only on recompile. Is this possible?

This is an example of what I'm attempting in app B:

```
// get Context of Shared App
     sharedContext = this.createPackageContext("com.app.A",Context.CONTEXT_IGNORE_SECURITY);
// get desired preferences from app A
     myPrefs = sharedContext.getSharedPreferences(PREFERENCES,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
// keeping local copy of this listener
     listener = new SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener() {
     public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences myPrefs, String key) {
          if (key.equals(PREFERENCES)) {
                       // Do something
               Log.d("Test", "preferences were updated");
               }
          }
     };
// register listener
myPrefs.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(listener);
```

Comment: I just found: "You can also set android:process so that components of different applications run in the same process—provided that the applications share the same Linux user ID and are signed with the same certificates." -- maybe this is a viable path?

Comment: Definetly a step in the right direction - sharing objects between processes is impossible, and thus listening to changes in another process without IPC is also impossible.

Comment: The listener is now picking up :)! Sometimes it's funny how you're stuck on a problem, and as soon as you communicate, you find the answer..

Comment: In this case, please answer your own question and mark the answer as accepted to mark this question as resolved and to hel pothers with a similar problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set `android:process` in the manifest of each app.

Also `key.equals(PREFERENCES)` should be the name of the specific preference to grab, `key.equals("key:example")` rather than the name of the shared Preference.